verify-imports return error: Missing dependencies
i try to run  npx verify-imports
And i have got error:
Missing  Dependencies
all missing dependencies are from @shared folder. This folder just and aliase to ./shared/ where I have got my components
So for all imports like
import { SomeComponent } from "@shared/somponents/somecomponent"

it returns an error missing dependencies
Build and app running correctly
I have a problem only with this verify-imports
I tried
npx verify-imports --ignore "/^@shared/"
npx verify-imports --ignore="/^@shared/"
npx verify-imports --ignore "@shared/"
npx verify-imports --ignore /^@shared/
npx verify-imports --ignore "@shared/*"

and many other combinations
could you help me please?
